# How can I return a List to the StreamBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am asking this a lot here, I know, but nobody gives me a right answer.

I just need to return a list with values from a sub collection of Firebase.

This is my code:

```
  List mapToList({DocumentSnapshot doc, List<DocumentSnapshot> docList}) {
    if (docList != null) {
      List<Store> storeList = [];
      docList.forEach((document) async {
        String productName;
        String name = document.data[StringConstant.nameField];

        QuerySnapshot productRef = await document.reference.collection('products').getDocuments();
        productRef.documents.forEach((value){
          productName = value["name"];
        });

          Store otherStore = Store(name, productName);
          storeList.add(otherStore);

      });
      print(storeList.length);
      return storeList;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Or I want something like this:

```
List mapToList({DocumentSnapshot doc, List<DocumentSnapshot> docList}) {
    if (docList != null) {
      List<Store> storeList = [];
      docList.forEach((document) async {
        //I KNOW THIS IS WRONG, BUT I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THE LINE BELOW
        String productName = document.data.reference.collection("products").data["productName];

        String name = document.data["name];
          Store otherStore = Store(name, productName);
          storeList.add(otherStore);
      });
      return storeList;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

How can I get this list?

Comment: A Collection in Firebase is unfortunately always only going to be a collection of documents. Could you clarify exactly why you absolutely need this kind of list access?

Comment: Hi! What I want to do is access a field in subcolletion and if the value of the field matches with my search, it calls the sub collection parent and built a list.

I need a list that have itens from the collection and itens from its subcolletion.

Comment: Subcollections do not have "fields". As is explained in [The Cloud Firestore Data Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), collections and subcollections both are just names for a set of documents. You cannot access fields directly in a subcollection, you must first reference a document in the subcollection, and then the document's fields. Documents are the only things that contain fields. Why not just put the productName field in the original documents?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! You should put this as an answer so I can thank you in a better way. 

Anyway, I want a collection of Stores that has documents with name, address, etc. and I want a Subcolletion that has the products of the Store. 

But you are the second person that tell me that... So why does firebase has sub collection if it is independente of the parent? Doest make sense.

Comment: Not what you said doesn't make sense but Firebase. You help me a lot because I'll use other approach from now.

Answer (score 1):

Subcollections do not have "fields" that you can access directly in the manner you wish to. As is explained in [The Cloud Firestore Data Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections), collections and subcollections both are essentially just names for a set of documents. You cannot access fields directly in a subcollection, you must first reference a document in the subcollection, and then the document's fields. Documents are the only things that contain fields.

For your situation, I'd suggest simply storing a map in the products field of each of the documents you're considering here. Or, if you absolutely must use a subcollection (perhaps as a means of keeping flexibility for future schema changes), use `document.collection('products').document('productName')["value"]` or something similar.

Subcollections work like this because they are inteded to provide a method to store data relevant only to a particular document, such that the document's security settings are thus also inherently applied to the subcollection. As in the example in the link - `rooms` is a collection of chatrooms, each of which is a document with its name and a reference to a `messages` subcollection, each of which contains the message and its author. The `messages` subcollection loses context without the `room` document.